# Combination of N elements in L groups of K items in python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, combinatorics

Given a list of N elements, e.g.

```
mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

I want to find all the combinations of K elements in L groups, e.g. for `K=4`, `L=2`,
it will results as

```
          L=0            L=1 
 1)   [0, 1, 2, 3]   [4, 5, 6, 7]
 2)   [0, 1, 2, 4]   [3, 5, 6, 7]
 3)   [0, 1, 2, 5]   [3, 4, 6, 7]

              ... etc...
69)   [4, 5, 6, 7]   [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Notice that `[0, 1, 2, 3]` and `[0, 1, 3, 2]` would be counted as the same combination for the first group.

For the case `L=2`, I am using the following

```py
from itertools import combinations

N = 8
M = 4
L = N // M

combs = list(combinations(range(N), M))
allidx = list(range(N))

for c, comb in enumerate(combs):

    idx1 = list(comb)
    idx2 = list(set(allidx) - set(idx1))

    print(c, idx1,'\t',idx2)
```

First, what is the mathematical definition of this type of 'combinations'?

Second, In the case `L>2`, is there a more efficient way to compute them than computing all the permutations and prune them after?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a recursive function, getting all combinations of `k` elements from the list, and combining them with the combinations for the remaining elements.

```
import itertools

def combs(lst, k, l):
    if l == 0:
        yield []
    else:
        for c in itertools.combinations(lst, k):
            rest = [x for x in lst if x not in c]
            for res in combs(rest, k, l-1):
                yield [c, *res]

mylist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
for res in combs(mylist, 4, 2):
    print(res)
```

Here, the part `rest = [x for x in lst if x not in c]` will only work if elements in the list are unique. If there can be duplicate elements, you can instead just get combinations of indices instead, e.g. like this (rest remains the same):

```
        for idc in itertools.combinations(range(len(lst)), k):
            comb = [lst[i] for i in idc]
            idc_set = set(idc)
            rest = [x for i, x in enumerate(lst) if i not in idc_set]
            for res in combs(rest, k, l-1):
                yield [comb, *res]
```

(Also, this assumes that `lst` has at least `l*k` elements.)

Comment: Maybe a typo?
`yield [comb, *rest]` --> `yield [comb, *res]`

Comment: @Chutlhu Oh my, yes of course! In my defense, in the case of k=2 both yields almost the same result, just a missing pair of parens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is approach that generates all unique partitions of size k from the set of length n.

Number of such partitions is (p is number of parts, equal to your L):

```
NPK(n,k) = n! / ((k!)^p * p!)
```

and grows fast (280 for n=9,k=3).

Algorithm recursively distributes items over parts. To avoid repeated generation of the same partition (like `01 23 45` and `01 45 23`), we should restrict places for leading (the smallest) element of every group.

Here I used `lastfilled` parameter for index of the rightmost filled part, so item 0 always belongs to the 0-th part, item 1 might fall into parts 0 or 1 but not into part 2 and so on. Having intermediate result `01 __ __` we can make only `01 2_ __` at the next level, not `01 __ 2_`.

```
def genp(l, parts, cnts, n, k, p,  m, lastfilled):
    if m == n:
        l.append(parts[:])
        return
    for i in range(min(p, lastfilled + 2)):
        if cnts[i] < k:
            parts[i][cnts[i]] = m
            cnts[i] += 1
            genp(l, parts, cnts, n, k, p, m+1, max(i, lastfilled))
            cnts[i] -= 1


def genpartssizek(n, k):
    l = []
    p = n // k
    parts = [[0]*k for _ in range(p)]
    cnts = [0]*p
    genp(l, parts, cnts, n, k, p,  0, -1)
    return l

print(genpartssizek(6,2))

[[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]], 
 [[0, 1], [2, 4], [3, 5]], 
 [[0, 1], [2, 5], [3, 4]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 3], [4, 5]], 
 [[0, 2], [1, 4], [3, 5]], 
 [[0, 2], [1, 5], [3, 4]], 
 [[0, 3], [1, 2], [4, 5]], 
 [[0, 4], [1, 2], [3, 5]], 
 [[0, 5], [1, 2], [3, 4]], 
 [[0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]], 
 [[0, 3], [1, 5], [2, 4]], 
 [[0, 4], [1, 3], [2, 5]], 
 [[0, 5], [1, 3], [2, 4]], 
 [[0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3]], 
 [[0, 5], [1, 4], [2, 3]]]
```